# Is $A - B = \emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

$A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}, B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

$A - B =$ ?

Does that just leave me with $\emptyset$?  Or do I do something with the leftover $6,7,8$?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. Not that it's $\emptyset$, and not $\{\emptyset\}$ here.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A - B = \emptyset$, because by definition, $A - B$ is everything that is in $A$ but not in $B$.